# Type inference from parameter type

Tags: dart

Consider the following example:

```
typedef Action<T> = void Function(T arg);

void execute<T>(T arg, Action<T> action) => action(arg);

void main() {
  execute(42, (value) => print(value.bar));
}
```

I would expect the Dart Analyzer to fail at `value.bar` since `T` could be inferred to `number`. Instead, Dart does not infer `T` to `number`, but falls back to `dynamic`.

Is there a way to parameter-driven type-inference in Dart?

If not, is there a list a way to prohibit defaulting to `dynamic`?

EDIT:

Equivalent example in TypeScript:

```
type Action<T> = (arg: T) => void;

function execute<T>(arg: T, action: Action<T>) {
    return action(arg);
}

function main() {
  execute(42, (value) => console.log(value.bar));
}
```

yields error

```
Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Equivalent example in Kotlin:

```
typealias Action<T> = (arg: T) -> Unit;

fun<T> execute(arg: T, action: Action<T>) = action(arg);

fun main() {
  execute(42) { value -> print(value.bar) };
}
```

yields error

```
Unresolved reference: bar
```

Answer (score -1):

I investigated this issue and discovered that if you simply write

```dart
execute(42, (value) => print(value));
```

then the type will be correct inferred to be `int`. I believe when attempting to infer a type, the analyzer is looking to the find the smallest type the matches both parameters. It can infer from the first parameter that it must be at least an `int`. However, when it analyzes the lambda on the second parameter, it infers that `value` cannot be and `int` because `int` does not have `bar` so it falls back to `dynamic` as the only type that that type parameter can be.

If you think this is not the way the type inference should work, you should submit an issue to the sdk: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues